# Access: Passing Parameters from Form to Query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm writing a query in Access 2013.  The query will use the parameters from a form, pass those parameters to the query, and then display the results.  I almost have it working.  The problem with this form is that there are multiple date fields.  There are two text fields (*txtFromDate* and *txtToDate*).

The idea is that user can enter date range one of two ways:

1. the user can click the date picker and select a date range to pass to the query;
2. the user can choose the *Fiscal Year* from a combobox.

I have created a separate table that is setup as follows:

```
Table:    tbl_FiscalYear
Columns:  FiscalYr_ID, FiscalYearName, FromDate, ToDate
```

In my query, the results work great (all parameters passed to query) if the user enters the manual dates in the txt fields.  However, if they bypass the manual date entry and use the *Fiscal Year* combobox, the query results ignore all previous parameters and the results only reflect the appropriate date range per the *Fiscal Year* date setup in the fiscal year table.

I think the culprit is the `OR` statement at the end.  Is there a way to incorporate both date search parameters into the form, and allowing the use of one or the other?  Is my code not correct since it doesn't allow passing null values from the text date fields?

```
SELECT tbl_QUOTE.QUOTE_ID, 
       tbl_QUOTE.QUOTE_DATESTART, 
       tbl_QUOTE.QUOTE_DATEEND, 
       tbl_QUOTE.QUOTE_lookup_POC_ID, 
       tbl_QUOTE.QUOTE_lookup_LOC_ID, 
       tbl_QUOTE.QUOTE_lookup_TRAINER_NAME, 
       tbl_QUOTE.QUOTE_lookup_STATUS_ID, 
       tbl_QUOTE.QUOTE_lookup_TRAINER_ID, 
       tbl_QUOTE.QUOTE_lookup_MODS_ID, 
       tbl_POC.POC_AGENCY_lookup, 
       tbl_QUOTE.QUOTE_FINANCIAL_CD, 
       tbl_FISCALYEAR.FISCALYEARNAME
FROM tbl_fiscalyear, tbl_QUOTE 
INNER JOIN tbl_POC ON tbl_QUOTE.QUOTE_lookup_POC_ID = tbl_POC.POC_ID
WHERE Nz([QUOTE_lookup_STATUS_ID],"") Like [Forms]![frm_QuoteReport]![cboStatusLookup] & "*"
AND Nz([tbl_POC].[POC_AGENCY_lookup],"") Like [Forms]![frm_QuoteReport]![cboAgency] & "*"
AND Nz([QUOTE_lookup_POC_ID],"") Like [Forms]![frm_QuoteReport]![cboPOC] & "*"
AND Nz([QUOTE_lookup_MODS_ID],"") Like [Forms]![frm_QuoteReport]![cboCourse] & "*"
AND Nz([QUOTE_lookup_LOC_ID],"") Like [Forms]![frm_QuoteReport]![cboLocation] & "*"
AND Nz([QUOTE_lookup_Trainer_ID],"") Like [Forms]![frm_QuoteReport]![cboTrainer] & "*"
AND Nz([Fiscalyr_ID],"") Like [Forms]![frm_QuoteReport]![cboFY] & "*"
AND Nz([Quote_Financial_Cd],"") Like [Forms]![frm_QuoteReport]![chkFundCd] & "*"
AND [QUOTE_DATESTART] Between [Forms]![frm_QuoteReport]![txtFromDate] 
                          And [Forms]![frm_QuoteReport]![txtToDate]
OR [QUOTE_DATESTART] 
BETWEEN (SELECT [tbl_fiscalyear].[fromdate] 
         FROM tbl_fiscalyear 
         WHERE fiscalyr_ID = [Forms]![frm_QuoteReport]![cboFY]) 
    AND (SELECT [tbl_fiscalyear].[todate] 
         FROM tbl_fiscalyear 
         WHERE fiscalyr_ID = [Forms]![frm_QuoteReport]![cboFY]);
```

Comment: Edit:  I removed the date text field entirely and the parameters pass fine using the combobox.  So I'm assuming that there's something wrong with the way I'm handling the date text fields, but I'm not sure what it is.

Comment: I believe I resolved it.  I edited the final lines as follows:
    OR [QUOTE_DATESTART] Between [Forms]![frm_QuotesReports]![txtFromDate] And [Forms]![frm_QuotesReports]![txtToDate]
    AND [QUOTE_DATESTART] BETWEEN (SELECT [tbl_fiscalyear].[fromdate] FROM tbl_fiscalyear WHERE fiscalyr_ID = [Forms]![frm_QuotesReports]![cboFY]) AND (SELECT [tbl_fiscalyear].[todate] FROM tbl_fiscalyear WHERE fiscalyr_ID = [Forms]![frm_QuotesReports]![cboFY])

Comment: How is this query being used? As recordsource to a form or just a saved query opened to screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I resolved it. I edited the final lines as follows:

```
   OR [QUOTE_DATESTART] Between [Forms]![frm_QuotesReports]![txtFromDate] 
    And [Forms]![frm_QuotesReports]![txtToDate] <br/> AND [QUOTE_DATESTART] 
    BETWEEN (SELECT [tbl_fiscalyear].[fromdate] FROM tbl_fiscalyear WHERE 
    fiscalyr_ID = [Forms]![frm_QuotesReports]![cboFY]) AND (SELECT 
    [tbl_fiscalyear].[todate] FROM tbl_fiscalyear WHERE fiscalyr_ID = [Forms]!
    [frm_QuotesReports]![cboFY])
```